# How to specify the Z direction(depth) for a cube

Tags: java, 3d

I would like to know how can I specify the z-direction for my cube. It needs to be translated to -5 along z-direction. 
The whole problem statement is like this: Implement the transformation pipeline, by defining a cube in 3d space, setting up a camera in the origin of the coordinate system and a projection matrix that has a 90° FOV. The cube size should be 2 unites (2x2x2), laid down 5 unites along the negative z axis
    package transformations;

```
import java.util.*;

import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;

public class Transformations {

        //declare list of polygons
        static ArrayList<Integer>p_left=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        static ArrayList<Integer>p_right=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        static ArrayList<Integer>p_down=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        static ArrayList<Integer>p_top=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        static ArrayList<Integer>p_near=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        static ArrayList<Integer>p_far=new ArrayList<Integer>();


        static int count=0;
        public static BufferedImage gradientSetRaster(BufferedImage img) {
            int width = img.getWidth();
            int height = img.getHeight();

            WritableRaster raster = img.getRaster();
            int[] pixel = new int[3]; //RGB

                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                    int val = (int) (y * 255f / height);
                    for (int shift = 1; shift < 3; shift++) {
                        pixel[shift] = val;
                    }

                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                        raster.setPixel(x, y, pixel);
                    }
                }

            return img;
        }

        public static BufferedImage drawLine(BufferedImage img, int x0, int y0, int xn, int yn) 
        {
            WritableRaster raster=img.getRaster();

            int[] pixel = new int[3]; //RGB
            for(int k=0; k<3; k++) 
            {
                pixel[k]=255;
            }

            int dx=Math.abs(xn-x0);
            int dy=Math.abs(yn-y0);
            int m=dy/dx;
            int twoDy=2*dy;
            int twoDyMintwoDx=twoDy-2*dx;

            if(dx>dy)   //slope is positive and is less than or equal to 1 
            {
                int p=twoDy-dx;

                for(int k=0; k<dx-1; k++) 
                {
                    if(p<0) 
                    {
                        x0=x0+1;
                        raster.setPixel(x0, y0, pixel);
                        p=p+twoDy;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        x0=x0+1;
                        y0=y0+1;
                        raster.setPixel(x0, y0, pixel);
                        p=p+twoDy-2*dx;
                    }

                }
            }

            if(dy>dx) 
            {
                int p=2*dx-dy;
                int temp1=x0;
                x0=y0;
                y0=temp1;

                int temp2=xn;
                xn=yn;
                yn=temp2;

                for(int k=0; k<dx-1; k++) 
                {
                    x0=x0+1;
                    y0=y0+1;
                    raster.setPixel(x0, y0, pixel);
                }
            }

            if(dy==dx) 
            {
                x0=x0+1;
                y0=y0+1;

                raster.setPixel(x0, y0, pixel);
            }


            return img;
        }

        public static BufferedImage drawUpPolygon(Graphics g, BufferedImage img, ArrayList<Integer>p_top) 
        {
            g.drawLine(p_top.get(0), p_top.get(1), p_top.get(2), p_top.get(3));
            g.drawLine(p_top.get(0), p_top.get(1), p_top.get(4), p_top.get(5));
            g.drawLine(p_top.get(4), p_top.get(5), p_top.get(6), p_top.get(7));
            g.drawLine(p_top.get(6), p_top.get(7), p_top.get(2), p_top.get(3));

            return img;
        }

        public static BufferedImage drawDownPolygon(Graphics g, BufferedImage img, ArrayList<Integer>p_top) 
        {
            g.drawLine(p_down.get(0), p_down.get(1), p_down.get(2), p_down.get(3));
            g.drawLine(p_down.get(0), p_down.get(1), p_down.get(4), p_down.get(5));
            g.drawLine(p_down.get(4), p_down.get(5), p_down.get(6), p_down.get(7));
            g.drawLine(p_down.get(6), p_down.get(7), p_down.get(2), p_down.get(3));

            return img;
        }

        public static BufferedImage drawBetween(Graphics g, BufferedImage img, ArrayList<Integer>p_top, ArrayList<Integer>p_down) 
        {
            g.drawLine(p_top.get(0), p_top.get(1), p_down.get(0), p_down.get(1));
            g.drawLine(p_top.get(2), p_top.get(3), p_down.get(2), p_down.get(3));
            g.drawLine(p_top.get(4), p_top.get(5), p_down.get(4), p_down.get(5));
            g.drawLine(p_top.get(6), p_top.get(7), p_down.get(6), p_down.get(7));

            return img;
        }



        public static void main(String... args) {
            Frame w = new Frame("Raster");  //window
            final int imageWidth = 500;
            final int imageHeight = 500;

            w.setSize(imageWidth,imageHeight);
            w.setLocation(100,100);
            w.setVisible(true);

            Graphics g = w.getGraphics();

            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            gradientSetRaster(img);
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, (img1, infoflags, x, y, width, height) -> false);  //draw the image. You can think of this as the display method.


            w.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    //order will be(vertex->index)
                    //lowerLeft->0,1
                    //upperLeft->2,3
                    //lowerRight->4,5
                    //upperRight->6,7
                    count++;

                    int t_lowLeftX=e.getX();
                    int t_lowLeftY=e.getY();
                    //top polygon                       
                    int t_lowRightX;
                    int t_lowRightY;

                    int t_uppLeftX;
                    int t_uppLeftY;

                    int t_uppRightX;
                    int t_uppRightY;

                    //bottom polygon
                    int d_lowLeftX;
                    int d_lowLeftY;

                    int d_lowRightX;
                    int d_lowRightY;

                    int d_uppLeftX;
                    int d_uppLeftY;

                    int d_uppRightX;
                    int d_uppRightY;

                    if(count==1) {
                        //lowerLeft indexes
                        t_lowLeftX=e.getX();
                        t_lowLeftY=e.getY();

                        t_lowRightX=t_lowLeftX+100;
                        t_lowRightY=t_lowLeftY;

                        t_uppLeftX=t_lowLeftX+50;
                        t_uppLeftY=t_lowLeftY+50;

                        t_uppRightX=t_uppLeftX+100;
                        t_uppRightY=t_uppLeftY;

                        d_lowLeftX=t_lowLeftX;
                        d_lowLeftY=t_lowLeftY-70;

                        d_lowRightX=t_lowRightX;
                        d_lowRightY=t_lowRightY-70;

                        d_uppLeftX=t_uppLeftX;
                        d_uppLeftY=t_uppLeftY-70;

                        d_uppRightX=t_uppRightX;
                        d_uppRightY=t_uppRightY-70;


                        //connect(lowLeft->uppLeft, lowLeft->lowRight, uppLeft->uppRight, 
                        //uppRight->lowRight ...)   
                        p_top.add(t_lowLeftX);
                        p_top.add(t_lowLeftY); 
                        p_top.add(t_lowRightX);
                        p_top.add(t_lowRightY);
                        p_top.add(t_uppLeftX);
                        p_top.add(t_uppLeftY);
                        p_top.add(t_uppRightX);
                        p_top.add(t_uppRightY);

                        p_down.add(d_lowLeftX);
                        p_down.add(d_lowLeftY);
                        p_down.add(d_lowRightX);
                        p_down.add(d_lowRightY);
                        p_down.add(d_uppLeftX);
                        p_down.add(d_uppLeftY);
                        p_down.add(d_uppRightX);
                        p_down.add(d_uppRightY);



//                      g.drawLine(lowLeftX, lowLeftY, uppLeftX, uppLeftY);
//                      g.drawLine(lowLeftX, lowLeftY, lowRightX, lowRightY);
//                      g.drawLine(uppLeftX, uppLeftY, uppRightX, uppRightY);
//                      g.drawLine(uppRightX, uppRightY, lowRightX, lowRightY);

                        drawUpPolygon(g, img, p_top);
                        drawDownPolygon(g, img, p_down);
                        drawBetween(g, img, p_top, p_down);

                        int[] pixel = {255,255,255};
                        img.getRaster().setPixel(t_lowLeftX,t_lowLeftY,pixel);
                        img.getRaster().setPixel(t_uppLeftX, t_uppLeftY,pixel);                 
                        img.getRaster().setPixel(t_lowLeftX, t_lowLeftY, pixel);
                        img.getRaster().setPixel(t_lowRightX, t_lowRightY, pixel);
                        img.getRaster().setPixel(t_uppRightX, t_uppRightY, pixel);

                        img.getRaster().setPixel(d_lowLeftX,d_lowLeftY,pixel);
                        img.getRaster().setPixel(d_uppLeftX, d_uppLeftY,pixel);                 
                        img.getRaster().setPixel(d_lowLeftX, d_lowLeftY, pixel);
                        img.getRaster().setPixel(d_lowRightX, d_lowRightY, pixel);
                        img.getRaster().setPixel(d_uppRightX, d_uppRightY, pixel);


                    };



                    //top polygon's lower left vertex                   

                }
            });


            w.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    w.dispose();
                    g.dispose();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, normally you'd do the following: 1) from your camera position, the direction it looks to and the fov you create your projection matrix. 2) you set the world coordinates of your cube accordingly, e.g. you move its center by -5 units along the direction the camera looks to. 3) From the cube's local matrix (which would represent any local rotation and scaling), the world matrix (which represents the cube's position in the world) and the projection matrix you form a transformation matrix for the cube's vertices and calculate their positions in view space.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but it still remains unclear how cube specified in 2D which has only x and y coordinates for its points can be multiplied by any 3D transformation matrix

Comment: In essence in a first narrowing, you are correct, you cannot actually display 3d on a 2d display as it has no depth(and same holds true for your 2d objects). You can however create an impression/illusion of depth by projecting the 3D on the 2D. The projection matrix you use is something you have to decide on and implement. One common is using 45°  and scaling by 1/2 for z.  Translating the 2D by this gives an impression of depth. (another common is uisng 30°/30°)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axonometry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_video_game_graphics

Comment: thanks for more clarification, so if I understood properly, I must define 3D points for my polygon coordinates and then when I reach viewport transformation part then they will become 2D points by my projection matrix. Am I right?

Comment: I don't know what you constraints are(what requirements your special case needs to fullfill). In general I would define the 3D objects(even if they are planes) with 3D coordinates. For drawing I'd multiply them with a projection matrix and draw the result on the canvas. That is also how gl or directx does it. Your special case may have speccial requirements and you may define as two d and generate the 2d by a simple tranformation projection - can't say - its your requirements(And having the choice I'd actually use a 3D library that does everything and utilizes the graphicscard).

Comment: Implement the transformation pipeline, by defining a cube in 3d space, setting up a camera in the origin of the coordinate system and a projection matrix that has a 90° FOV. • The cube size should be 2 unites (2x2x2), laid down 5 unites along the
negative z axis.
• The cube must be described by a class which contains a list of polygons,
each polygon has an ordered list of vertices (4 vertices) describing a face.
• You need a world matrix in order to translate the cube to its location.
• A camera matrix that is set to identity at the beginning.
• And a projection matrix handles 90° FOV

Comment: Here is the task description

Comment: yes but that doesnt say how your vertices are defined ;). I would start by defining a vertex and having the choice I'd use 3 to 4 coordinates for a vertex. The forth is not needed but may help for calculations.  Eg an array with 3/4 fields or a "Vertex" object with the fields x,y,z - or better something combining it: a object with getter/setter for x,yand z, backed by an array to store the coordinates. Having  an array has some advantaged for calculation(An array  is a vector).

Comment: thanks, I will think about it

Comment: That task description looks like you should implement a normal transformation pipeline, i.e. no special cases. It also states that the cube should be defined in 3d so your vertices need at least 3 coordinates. Also "A camera matrix that is set to identity _at the beginning_." indicates your application will be expanded so don't go for the simple route right from the start but try to do it properly. The vertices of the cube would have coordinates of (+/-1,+/-1,+/-1) which effectively creates a 2x2x2 cube (note that those coordinates are in object space).

Comment: If you need to draw the cube's faces yourself you basically iterate over them and draw a polygon using its 4 vertices which are transformed from 3d object space to world space by applying the world matrix, then to camera space by applying the camera matrix (representing the orientation and position of the camera) and finally to view space by applying the projection matrix. Note that you'd also need to either do z-buffering (might be too advanced yet) or [backface culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling) (you don't draw faces that don't face the camera).